# UICollectionView SupplementaryView Add UIButton to Footer

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, footer, supplementary

Does anyone know how to add a button to a supplementaryView footer that is inside of an `UICollectionView`?  I tried to code one but I keep getting errors, and I currently have this error in the `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind` function; error:

> invalid redeclaration of
>   'collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:)'

Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Nice Tutorail available on appcoda regarding the Supplementary View In Collection View.

[Click Here](http://www.appcoda.com/supplementary-view-uicollectionview-flow-layout/)